# Matching vertices in igraph (R)

Tags: r, network, vertices

I'm currently using a combination of ArcMap 10.2 and igraph in R to analyse a network with associated data.  I have an igraph network object based on the OS ITN network with associated TOIDs for each road segment and weights based on distance.  I also have a second network dataset (Shapefile format) that contains TOIDs for each segment, start and end node.

What I'm looking to do is match the second dataset to the first to create a graph object that is weighted according to different criteria (activity counts).  So I need to match the road segments, then create the new graph object, then I'll be able to compare shortest paths (distance vs activity count).

My starting point is something like this...

```
inds <- match(someIDs, ITNAdjOneWayUpper$IDs)
V(ITNNodeGraphNew)[which(!is.na(inds))]$weights
```

I'm just not sure what I should be entering to create the new graph object.